# Oracle EBS XML Publisher Report using .XLS Template

Tags: oraclereports, oracle-ebs, oracle-bi, oracle-xml-publisher

I'm using a .XLS template instead of .RTF.

The problem is, even when I format the excel field cell to Text, I'm still getting `#NUM!` in the output.

The template is considering the data as an exponential value because of the character "E" in between the numbers. The exact value to be displayed in output is "**12E18157**" but I get `#NUM!` no matter what I do.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was not successful in trying to format the .xls template cell because no matter how we format the cell, the template is considering the value as exponential value so I have concatenated a space for that particular column in my query(XML Data Definition file) itself and it fixed the problem.